# System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Search.ResultSet to Search.Result

Tags: apex, visualforce, json

i have json string like this downbelow

```
{"0":{"in":"mmm","loc":"1234"},"1":{"in":"mmm","loc":"1234"}}
```

Now i need to parse them as like

```
in | loc
---------
mmm| 1234
mmm| 1234
```

So far i did

```
public with sharing class Search 
{ 
    public String strTag {get;set;}
    public String strlocation {get;set;}
    public String result {get;set;}

    public PageReference find() {         

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    Http http = new Http();

    req.setEndpoint('http://test.3spire.net/index.php?in='+strTag+'&loc='+strlocation);
    req.setMethod('GET');

    //these parts of the POST you may want to customize
    req.setCompressed(false);
    req.setBody('key1=value1&key2=value2');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');  

    try {
        res = http.send(req);       
    } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
        system.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
        result = ''+e;
    }

    Result results = (Result) JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),ResultSet.class);

    result = res.getBody();
    system.debug(res.getBody());
        return null;
    }

    public class ResultSet{       
        public List<Result> resultSet;
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public String ins;
        public String loc;
    }
}
```

But its returns

> System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type
>   Search.ResultSet to Search.Result

How can i solved this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: issue with `JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),ResultSet.class)`.. debug `res.getBody()` and create a class for deserialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
Result results = (Result) JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),ResultSet.class);
```

You initialize a variable of type `Result` and try to cast the result of `JSON.deserialize()` to a `Result`. However, the second parameter of the `JSON.deserialize()` function makes the function return an instance of `ResultSet`.

I think you want to change the type of the variable to ResultSet.

There are some more problems, however. The ResultSet class should not have a `List<Result>` field, but a `Map<String, Result>`, because the JSON also has a map. Also, your `Result` class has a field called `ins`, but in the JSON the name is `in`.

Comment: it's worked.But how can i bind them with pageblocktable